# JSF Converter - Not invoked if text is read only

Tags: java, jsf, converters

**Context :** One of the application has a xhtml form where a text area would be rendered as disabled field.

**Problem :** And when user submits the form, the converter associated with that field doesn't get invoked, but works fine when the text area is not disabled. 
Is this how JSF request/response life cycle works or, am I missing something ?

**Pseudo Code:**

```
<tag:field id="xyz" label="abc" value="#{something.something}" 
    disaply="mutable" required="false" styleClass="Text_Area" 
    disabled="#{somethingelse.something}" rows = "4" cols="50"
    converter="freeTextConverter">
</tag:field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1), the values of disabled input fields are **not** sent along with the form submit. So JSF simply got `null` as value and there's nothing to convert. You perhaps want to use `readonly` instead. This way the value is not editable, but it will be sent along with the form submit. You only need to take into account that the client can still tamper the request and edit the value before it get sent. You'd perhaps want to store the value in a view scoped bean instead and keep the field disabled.